# Accessing the global variable of a window from its tabs in jquery

Tags: jquery, global-variables, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a html page made of jquery tabs. Each tab loads data from another html page. I am setting a global variable in the container html page and i want to access the same in its tabs. How do i do that? I tried window.var , window.parent.var, this.var etc. But nothing works. I have attached the code. kindly help.

**Container html page.**

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="../../css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
<link type="text/css" href="./methodeditor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( ".tabs" ).tabs({cache:true});
    });  
</script>
<script>

var method = " ";
function setmethod(m) {
    method = m;
}
function loadtabs(){


          method = window.parent.method;
          setmethod(method);
          $("#oven").load('oven.html');
          $("#detectors").load('detectors.html');
          $("#inlets").load('inlets.html');

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="editor" action="method.php" method="POST" >
<div class="editor">

<div class="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#oven">Temperature</a></li>
        <li><a href="#detectors">Timing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#inlets">Vial and Loop</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="oven" ></div>
    <div id="detectors" ></div>
    <div id="inlets"> </div>

</div>
<script>
loadtabs();
</script>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**oven.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function getvalues() {
          file = window.method;
          //file = m;
          file = "./method/"+file;
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.open("GET", file, false);
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
          xmlhttp.send("");
          xmldoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
          etimenode = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("method")[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1];
          etime = etimenode.textContent;
          document.getElementById("etime").value =  etime;    
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="oventemp" value="ON" />Oven Temperature
Equilibrium time <input type="text" id="etime"  />
<script>
getvalues();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried just accessing it directly? It's a global variable so should be freely available.

Comment: I tried accessing it directly, but i cant get the value

Answer (score 0):

You could include the variables you need in the string that loads the page, like:

```
setmethod(method);
$("#oven").load('oven.html?var1=' + myvar1 + '&var2=' + myvar2 );
```

Then in oven.html you can use a method [similar to these](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html) to grab these as global vars that will work in the scope of that loaded page: